# "Assigned To" automatic emails

Tags: 2013, list, email, alert, task-list

I'm using the "Assigned To" field to automatically send an email alert when a new item is added to my task list.

I was wondering if there was a way to change the order of the fields in the body of that email alert to match the order of my task list in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing **Column Order** in Content Type of you SharePoint List similar to match the order of your task list.

**Reference**:

[How to change the order of columns in a SharePoint list or library](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-change-the-order-of-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, no luck..because I have content types enabled this is how I have to change the order of the task list.  I checked all the views I have set up and none of them match the order that is found in the email alert body.

Comment: Is it not the same the order as you have in your list forms?

Comment: The body of the email alert has a different order than the order of the questions in my list.  It looks like the order of the email alert is the order that I created the columns. I changed the column order in the list but the email alert still reflects the order that it was originally created in.

Answer (score 0):

Found this tip which answered my question and made it work: "you will need to disable content type management (Allow management of content types? = No) in order to change the column order. Once you have the column order to your liking you may re-enable content type management.: